# How to dynamically select the next instance of a class after a click in native JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, forms, user-interface, focus, tabindex

In an effort to make my form more accessible, what I'm trying to figure out is that if the user presses enter on either the `Agree` or `Disagree` button, the tab-focus should skip to the next `agree` button. I've added a class to every instance of `Agree` buttons (`next-btn`), so now I just need to write a function that focuses on the next instance of `next-btn`.

The HTML is as follows:

```
<form id="quiz" style="text-align: center;">
<div id="questions">
    <div class="list-group-item">
        <p>I often make spontaneous or last-minute decisions</p>
        <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified button-wrap">
            <div class="btn-group"><input tabindex="-1" type="radio" name="q1" id="yes-q1" value="yellow" class="btn agree-btn" required/><label tabindex="0" class="button-label next-btn" for="yes-q1">Agree</label></div>
            <div class="btn-group"><input tabindex="-1" type="radio" name="q1" id="no-q1" value="blue" class="btn disagree-btn"/><label tabindex="0" class="button-label" for="no-q1">Disagree</label></div>
        </div>
    </div>
<div class="list-group-item">
    <p>My ideas are often unconventional or radical</p>
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified button-wrap"> 
        <div class="btn-group"><input tabindex="-1" type="radio" name="q2" id="yes-q2" value="yellow" class="btn agree-btn" required/><label tabindex="0" class="button-label next-btn" for="yes-q2">Agree</label></div>
        <div class="btn-group"><input tabindex="-1" type="radio" name="q2" id="no-q2" value="blue" class="btn disagree-btn" required/><label tabindex="0" class="button-label" for="no-q2">Disagree</label></div>
    </div>
</div>
            <div class="list-group-item">
                <p>I am naturally inclined to step forward and lead the group</p>
                <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified button-wrap">
                    <div class="btn-group"><input tabindex="-1" type="radio" name="q3" id="yes-q3" value="red" class="btn agree-btn" required/><label tabindex="0" class="button-label next-btn" for="yes-q3">Agree</label></div>
                    <div class="btn-group"><input tabindex="-1" type="radio" name="q3" id="no-q3" value="blue" class="btn disagree-btn" required/><label tabindex="0" class="button-label" for="no-q3">Disagree</label></div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <button id="submit-btn" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" type="submit" value="Submit" style="margin-top: 50px;">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

and the relevant JavaScript I have written is here:

```
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".button-label");

for(let answerButton of buttons) {
    answerButton.addEventListener('keydown', focusHere);

    // Simulate click event on tab + entering (accessiblity feature)
    function focusHere(event) {
        if (event.key == 'Enter') {
            // Trigger the click for the input
            answerButton.click();
            // Set focus to the next Agree button (next question)
            document.querySelector(".next-btn").focus();
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone have suggestions on how I can specify the next instance of a class with my current form setup? I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I used `Array#forEach` to iterate through the array and get the index of the button.

So I use the `buttons` array because it contains all the `button.button-label` elements, and the `.next-btn` elements have the `.button-label` class.

So I slice the `buttons` array to return all the items in the array after the one that called the `focusHere` function, and found the first item or instance of the `.next-btn` element

```
const buttons = [...document.querySelectorAll(".button-label")];

buttons.forEach((answerButton, i) => {
    answerButton.addEventListener('keydown', focusHere);

    function focusHere(event) {
        if (event.key == 'Enter') {
            answerButton.click();
            buttons.slice(i).find(btn => btn.classList.contains('next-btn')).focus();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Hey, this did it! I figured it adding things to an array and iterating would be the right approach, but as a beginner I was unsure how to write it up. One thing I needed to modify was that `buttons.slice(i).find` should be `buttons.slice(i+1).find`. That change ensured that if the `agree` button was selected, it would skip to the next agree button and not refocus on the current element.